# Troubleshooting - How to mirror two cells from different sheets in Excel (2013) using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am working on a VBA setup for an extensive issue tracking file. I have one sheet that contains all of the issues, and is difficult to manage. I have another sheet which is designed to present the user with the 10 highest priority items for a given day, allow them to update those items and then retrieve more issues. Because of the way the data is mirrored I need the users to be able to manipulate the data on either sheet and have it mirror to the other sheet.

I found from another question some suggested code and I was able to make it work as long as I only have one cell mirrored, but as soon as I start duplicating the code to add in other cells (there are about 200 cells that need to be mirrored), all of the cells stop updating (including the one that was previously working).

The **other issue** I was seeing even before I added the extra cell mirroring code lines relates to how the sheet reports the ten highest priority items. I have created a macro that takes the first sheet (the hard to understand one) and sorts the data in a specific way and I have attached that macro to a button on the other page. When I press the button it correctly sorts the data in the first sheet, but the cell that was mirrored never updated. So I need to know **1)** How to adjust my code to allow for multiple cells to be mirrored, and **2)** How to make it so when I sort the first sheet using the button, the data updates on the second sheet.

The code that was working when I only had one set of mirrored cells was the following located in the Sheet 1 Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change_B2(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim B2 As Range, B2_1 As Range
    Set B2 = Range("B2")
    Set B2_1 = Sheets("Priority Table").Range("B2")
    If Intersect(Target, B2) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        B2_1.Value = B2.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

and the following located in the sheet 2 code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change_B2(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim B2 As Range, B2_1 As Range
    Set B2 = Range("B2")
    Set B2_1 = Sheets("Issue List").Range("B2")
    If Intersect(Target, B2) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        B2_1.Value = B2.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

What I currently have on sheet 1 is (I am including three of the reference cells instead of all 200+)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change_B2(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim B2 As Range, B2_1 As Range
    Set B2 = Range("B2")
    Set B2_1 = Sheets("Priority Table").Range("B2")
    If Intersect(Target, B2) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        B2_1.Value = B2.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub    

Private Sub Worksheet_Change_I2(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim I2 As Range, I2_1 As Range
    Set I2 = Range("I2")
    Set I2_1 = Sheets("Priority Table").Range("B3")
    If Intersect(Target, I2) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        I2_1.Value = I2.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change_P2_1(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim P2 As Range, P2_1 As Range
    Set P2 = Range("P2")
    Set P2_1 = Sheets("Priority Table").Range("B4")
    If Intersect(Target, P2) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        P2_1.Value = P2.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

And on sheet 2 the matching code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change_B2(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim B2 As Range, B2_1 As Range
    Set B2 = Range("B2")
    Set B2_1 = Sheets("Issue List").Range("B2")
    If Intersect(Target, B2) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        B2_1.Value = B2.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change_B3(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim B3 As Range, B3_1 As Range
    Set B3 = Range("B3")
    Set B3_1 = Sheets("Issue List").Range("I2")
    If Intersect(Target, B3) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        B3_1.Value = B3.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change_B4(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim B4 As Range, B4_1 As Range
    Set B4 = Range("B4")
    Set B4_1 = Sheets("Issue List").Range("P2")
    If Intersect(Target, B4) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        B4_1.Value = B4.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any help for both of these issues is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't `Exit Sub` when your check fails. This is causing almost all of your code to be bypassed. Instead check `If Not (Intersect(Target, "B2") Is Nothing) Then `, with appropriate `End If`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. It ended up being too large of a macro so I split it into 10 smaller macros to manage everything but that change is exactly what I needed.